# Can observations of cosmic super voids teach us anything about time, dark energy, or dark matter?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, dark-matter, dark-energy

Can observations of cosmic super voids teach us anything about...

1. Time - If gravity affects time is there a chance we could gain any further information from studying a region with lower than average matter density.
2. Dark Energy - Wouldn't the effects of dark energy be much more noticeable in a region containing more empty space?
3. Dark Matter - If the gravitational pull of the visible matter in the void does not match current observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time is affected noticeably by gravity only in strong gravitational fields, i.e. in the vicinity of compact objects, so time doesn't run differently in voids from average regions.

Dark matter (DM) and energy (DE), on the other hand, can to some extend be unveiled by studying voids.

The morphology of the voids is affected by the nature of the DE, so measuring the sphericity/oblateness of voids and comparing to suites of cosmological simulations with various implementations of DE can teach us about that.

Studying the change of voids over time can yield insight into the equation of state of DE. Of course, on human timescales a given void doesn't evolve, but they can be observed statistically at different redshifts.

As the DM distribution ("halo mass function") is slightly different in voids from the rest of the Universe, we can also learn about DM from studying the differences.

See e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4238) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3301).